# How to find the LCM of two monomials or polynomials

Tags: factoring

How would I go about finding the LCM of two monomials, such as $240a^2bc,700a^3b^2$ , or polynomials such as $240a^bc-3, 700a^3b^2+5$? The only quick way I could think of would be to multiply them together, but that isn't always the *least* common multiple, it's just *a* multiple.

*note: I'm not looking for the answer to the problem, I'd like to know how to do it myself

Comment: Over which ring? $ℤ[a,b,c]$ or $ℚ[a,b,c]$ or $ℂ[a,b,c]$?

Comment: Just as a comment, the answers are widely different in the 2 cases. For arbitrary polynomials you would have to go the way @Stefan4024 pointed. For monomials, only, there is a far easier shortcut as shown by @​RossMillikan, which can also be used if you happen to have the *full* factorizations available.

Comment: @dxiv ah, we have to write the full factorizations out anyway

Comment: @Saiid `we have to write the full factorizations out anyway` No, Euclid's algorithm for GCD (including the multivariate case) does not require factorizing any polynomial.

Comment: @dxiv for the monomials i mean

Comment: @Saiid Monomials are already "factorized" for you. In contrast, factorizing an arbitrary polynomial is a non trivial task, which is why it's important that Euclid's algorithm finds the GCD without requiring factorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to finding the LCM of two integers, where you factor them and take the maximum power of each prime, you take the maximum power of each variable.  The LCM of $a^2bc$ and $a^3b^2$ is therefore $a^3b^2c$.  You find the LCM of $240$ and $700$ the usual way and multiply it on the front.  If your polynomials have multiple terms, you need to factor them as completely as possible, then apply this approach.  So, for example, the LCM of $x^3-3x+2=(x-1)^2(x+2)$ and $x^4+5 x^3+6 x^2-4 x-8=(x+2)^3(x-1)$ is $(x-1)^2(x+2)^3$

Comment: That's a good guess, but it won't work if the OP really meant polynomials.

Comment: @dxiv:  I added a bit about that.

Comment: Yes, but it becomes messy quickly for multivariate polynomials. Don't know a way in the general case to get the LCM directly without somehow going through the GCD first. That said, the OP meant monomials most likely, though s/he should edit the question (and title) to make that clear.

Comment: @dxiv I actually meant both lol i mixed up the names and forgot to put the other part in

Answer (score 1):

Find the GCD of the polynomials, which can be done using the Euclid Algorithm and then use that

$$\frac{P \cdot Q}{GCD(P,Q)}$$

where $P,Q$ are some polynomials.